# how to calculate sovereignAccount for parachain?

Tags: parachain

are there any methods or tools?

```
such as parachain id is 1000.
```

how to get this parachain's sovereignAccount

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*UPDATE*:
[shawn's utils website](https://www.shawntabrizi.com/substrate-js-utilities/) has a "Para ID" to Address utility.

Here is parachain sovereign account 2000 (the AcountId32):

0x70617261 + d0070000 + 000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

0x70617261 = b"para" (up/down) or 0x7369626c = b"sibl" (side-to-side)

d0070000 = scale encoded number 2000

You can see the scale encoding of a u32 by typing the number into collatorSelection/setDesiredCandidates and looking at the encoded call details on the bottom right by `max` that is the encoded version of 2000.

[image]

To copy and paste:

1000: 0x70617261e8030000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

2000: 0x70617261d0070000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

2001: 0x70617261d1070000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

2002: 0x70617261d2070000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

(That's also enough examples that you could guess the rest. I do think that we need an easy way to get these from polkadot-js maybe from the parachain screen? - PRs welcome!)

If you want a normal polkadot/kusama address then you can use the "AccountId to Hex" at https://www.shawntabrizi.com/substrate-js-utilities/ - paste in the above on the right hand side as the hex and you will get the address calculated. For example, for 1000 parachain id it returns 5Ec4AhPZk8STuex8Wsi9TwDtJQxKqzPJRCH7348Xtcs9vZLJ

Comment: nice job.thanks

Comment: `subkey inspect` allows to get the public account in different formats

Answer (score 8):

`Id` (aka `ParaId`) implements `into_account_id()`, as described [here](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/645ae551fcce76f040af71d10ad429baf40b6c61/parachain/src/primitives.rs#L308). The code translates to `("para", id).encode()`, then decoded as a 32 byte account id, with trailing zeros if need be.

I am not aware of any tools, but probably it would be very easy to make one, or manually check them.

Answer (score 3):

Now, we have another choice `Subalfred`, a CLI toolbox.

```
# Sovereign address on relaychain.
subalfred key --type parachain 2000
public-key 0x70617261d0070000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 ParaId(2000)
Substrate 5Ec4AhPUwPeyTFyuhGuBbD224mY85LKLMSqSSo33JYWCazU4

# Sovereign address on sibling chain.
subalfred key --type sibling 2000
public-key 0x7369626cd0070000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 SiblId(2000)
Substrate 5Eg2fntJ27qsari4FGrGhrMqKFDRnkNSR6UshkZYBGXmSuC8

# Note that, if you are on Moonbeam-link chain, remove 24 trailing zeros from the public-key.
public-key 0x7369626cd0070000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 SiblId(2000)
public-key 0x7369626cd0070000000000000000000000000000 SiblId(2000)

# Subalfred will detect if this is a sovereign address automatically.
subalfred key 5Eg2fntJ27qsari4FGrGhrMqKFDRnkNSR6UshkZYBGXmSuC8
public-key 0x7369626cd0070000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 SiblId(2000)
Substrate 5Eg2fntJ27qsari4FGrGhrMqKFDRnkNSR6UshkZYBGXmSuC8
```

For more details, check the https://subalfred.hack.ink/user/cli/key.html.

Answer (score 2):

The answers above are brilliant, but just in case is useful for other devs I want to share a code snippet to calculate the Sovereign Account in Rust.

```rs
use scale::Encode;
use sp_core::{crypto::{Ss58AddressFormatRegistry, Ss58Codec}, sr25519::Pair};
use sp_runtime::{MultiSigner};

let sovereign_account_str = calculate_sovereign_account::<Pair>(para_id)?;

fn calculate_sovereign_account<Pair>(
    para_id: u32,
) -> Result<String, Box<dyn std::error::Error>>
where
    Pair: sp_core::Pair,
    Pair::Public: Into<MultiSigner>,
{
    // Scale encoded para_id
    let id = RococoId(para_id);
    let encoded_id = hex::encode(id.encode());

    // Prefix para or sibl
    let prefix = hex::encode("para"); 

    // Join both strings and the 0x at the beginning
    let encoded_key = "0x".to_owned() + &prefix + &encoded_id;

    // Fill the rest with 0s
    let public_str = format!("{:0<width$}", encoded_key, width = 64 + 2);

    // Convert hex public key to ss58 address
    let public = array_bytes::hex2bytes(&public_str).expect("Failed to convert hex to bytes");
    let public_key = Pair::Public::try_from(&public)
        .map_err(|_| "Failed to construct public key from given hex")?;

    Ok(public_key.to_ss58check_with_version(Ss58AddressFormatRegistry::SubstrateAccount.into()))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using python's `scalecodec` ([py-scale-codec](https://github.com/polkascan/py-scale-codec)), you can get it like:

```
from scalecodec.base import ScaleBytes
from scalecodec.types import U32
from scalecodec.utils.ss58 import ss58_encode


def get_parachain_sovereign_account(para_id, chain_type='para'):
    scale_encoded = chain_type.encode().hex()
    scale_encoded += U32(ScaleBytes(bytearray())).encode(para_id).to_hex()[2:]
    public_key = f"0x{scale_encoded + ''.join(['0' * (64 - len(scale_encoded))])}"
    print(
        f'\t  Account ID:\t{public_key}\n' + \
        f'\tSS58 Address:\t{ss58_encode(public_key)}'
    )
```

Then...

```
get_parachain_sovereign_account(1000)
>>>
      Account ID:   0x70617261e8030000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
    SS58 Address:   5Ec4AhPZk8STuex8Wsi9TwDtJQxKqzPJRCH7348Xtcs9vZLJ

get_parachain_sovereign_account(2000)
>>>
      Account ID:   0x70617261d0070000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
    SS58 Address:   5Ec4AhPUwPeyTFyuhGuBbD224mY85LKLMSqSSo33JYWCazU4
```