# Is there a link or guide on how to get a Sovereign Account Address?

Tags: parachain, xcm, account, rococo, hrmp

I'm currently working on opening an HRMP Channel on Rococo with another parachain. In order to do this, I need to send an XCM to the relay chain. One of the items within this message requires a parameter which is the Sovereign Account Address on the Relay.

I was wondering if anyone could provide a link or guide on how to get a Sovereign Account Address?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think this question is solved already here: https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/1200/how-to-calculate-sovereignaccount-for-parachain/1210#1210

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to calculate sovereignAccount for parachain?](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/1200/how-to-calculate-sovereignaccount-for-parachain)

Answer (score 2):

The quick way for Kusama and Polkadot is to check subscan for the proper parachain: https://kusama.subscan.io/parachain/2023

In the case of most parachains on Rococo, the `Owner` is also the `Sovereign Account`.
https://rococo.subscan.io/parachain/2000

You can also directly specify the parachain and it will be automatically converted!

```
X1: {
 Parachain: <parachain-id>
 }
```