# What is a "sovereign" account in Polkadot/Substrate?

Tags: account

I have seen "sovereign" accounts used in multiple places in the Polkadot ecosystem yet I cannot find a formal definition of what a "sovereign" account is.

What is a "sovereign" account in Polkadot/Substrate?

Answer (score 4):

In general terms, according to the [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/sovereign) "sovereign" is defined as:

> having the highest power or being completely independent

In regards to Polkadot/Substrate, Moonbeam has a nice [definition](https://docs.moonbeam.network/builders/xcm/overview/#general-xcm-definitions):

> Sovereign account — an account each chain in the ecosystem has, one
> for the relay chain and the other for other parachains. It is
> calculated as the blake2 hash of a specific word and parachain ID
> concatenated (blake2(para+ParachainID) for the sovereign account in
> the relay chain, and blake2(sibl+ParachainID) for the sovereign
> account in other parachains), truncating the hash to the correct
> length. The account is owned by root and can only be used through SUDO
> (if available) or democracy (technical committee or referenda). The
> sovereign account typically signs XCM messages in other chains in the
> ecosystem

Sovereign accounts are also defined in the [XCM Format](https://github.com/paritytech/xcm-format#13-vocabulary):

> An account controlled by a particular Consensus System, within some
> other Consensus System. There may be many such accounts or just one.
> If many, then this assumes and identifies a unique primary account.

Yet a pallet can also have a "sovereign" account. For example, the [treasury pallet uses](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/a47f200eebeb88a5bde6f1ed2be9728b82536dde/frame/treasury/src/lib.rs#L185) a `PalletId` to generate a sovereign account:

```rust
/// The treasury's pallet id, used for deriving its sovereign account ID.
#[pallet::constant]
type PalletId: Get<PalletId>;
```

This treasury's sovereign account is the account in which the treasury's pot of funds is held.

There is also a good post on how to calculate sovereign account IDs [here](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/1200/how-to-calculate-sovereignaccount-for-parachain/5316#5316).