# Are there two types of sovereign accounts in Polkadot/Substrate?

Tags: account

The treasury pallet has the following code:

```rust
/// The treasury's pallet id, used for deriving its sovereign account ID.
#[pallet::constant]
type PalletId: Get<PalletId>;
```

- https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/a47f200eebeb88a5bde6f1ed2be9728b82536dde/frame/treasury/src/lib.rs#L185

Some definitions of sovereign accounts are given here:

- [What is a "sovereign" account in Polkadot/Substrate?](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/5845/what-is-a-sovereign-account-in-polkadot-substrate)

Are there two types of sovereign accounts in Substrate/Polkadot? One from a [consensus perspective](https://github.com/paritytech/xcm-format#13-vocabulary) and the other from a general notion of what it means to be an account that is, for all intents and purposes, sovereign.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting viewpoint.

I just called the `PalletId` a pallet account before.

Yep, maybe we could call it the sovereign account of a pallet.

---

From the low-level, they are using the same algorithm. But with different key type ids.

https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/ca1f81cd0864ae0614aaff07fa121d2d42110586/primitives/runtime/src/traits.rs#L1715

https://github.com/hack-ink/subalfred/blob/04d565a79589395d788ea2c091bc2f675b2197ee/lib/core/src/key/mod.rs#L95-L103

Comment: Thanks for the input. The reason I am asking this is because it is written in the code's comment [here](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/a47f200eebeb88a5bde6f1ed2be9728b82536dde/frame/treasury/src/lib.rs#L185). So I am trying to get a complete definition of sovereign account. The definitions that I have found [here](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/5845/what-is-a-sovereign-account-in-polkadot-substrate) do not include a definition for a pallet sovereign account - I could not find one!