# whats the difference between the two different sovereign account addresses?

Tags: parachain, xcm, rococo, xcmp

[image]

There are different sovereign account addresses here, what are the differences?

Answer (score 2):

> [Sovereign Account](https://github.com/paritytech/xcm-format#13-vocabulary): An account controlled by a particular Consensus System, **within** some other Consensus System.

So sovereign account is in other chains, and for different chains, there may be different account formats, and the relative `MultiLocation` is also different.

For example: There is a parachainA(paraId2105), its sovereign account in Rococo is encode("para"+2105), because of parachainA is a parachain attached to Rococo. Its sovereign account in parachainB(paraId2000) is encode("sibl"+2105), because of parachainA and parachainB are sibling chains. As you see, the encod content is different due to the different relation of the chains. **And if you want to known the detail of the encoding, please check the answers under this question**: [how to calculate sovereignAccount for parachain?](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/1200/how-to-calculate-sovereignaccount-for-parachain/1210)