# What can a parachain sovereignAccount be used for and why does it differ the Treasury Account?

Tags: parachain, xcm, pallet-treasury, treasury

The question comes in three parts:

1. Each parachain has its own `sovereignAccount` which can be calculated as described in the answer to [this question](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/1200/how-to-calculate-sovereignaccount-for-parachain), but how is that account used since it can receive funds?
2. Given that, how can funds be spent from the `sovereignAccount`?

Related to this if a parachain also implements the Treasury Pallet, then another account can exist which will have its own address that can be uniquely configured by changing the `PalletId` in the runtime.

3. It is more obvious how this Treasury address can be used and spent, but would it be a bad idea to configure the treasury account identical to the `sovereignAccount`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're missing a very important thing, `SovereignAccount` is on other chains, not on your chain. But treasury is on your chain.

> Sovereign Account: An account controlled by a particular Consensus System, **within some other Consensus System**.

---

For q1: "*how is that account used since it can receive funds?*"

For example: ParaA has a sovereignAccount on ParaB, when ParaB `reserveTransfer` its native token to ParaA via XCM, the sovereignAccount of ParaA on ParaB(SoverA_onB) will receive the native tokens(tokenB), and then generate derivative assets(tokenBD) on ParaA. You can refer to [the related code](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/release-v0.9.36/xcm/xcm-executor/src/lib.rs#L310).

---

For q2: *"how can funds be spent from the sovereignAccount?"*
Following the above example, when ParaA `reserveTransfer` tokenBD to ParaB, the corresponding amount tokenBD will be destroyed and the tokenB in SoverA_onB account will be spent and transfered to the beneficiary account. You can refert to [the related code](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/release-v0.9.36/xcm/xcm-executor/src/lib.rs#L420).

---

For q3: *"it be a bad idea to configure the treasury account identical to the sovereignAccount?"*

As I said at the beginning, the sovereign account is not on your own chain, it is a concept introduced in XCM. Moreover, the sovereign accounts of the same chain on different chains are different due to the relative location.