# Is there a programmatic way to retrieve list of parachain sovereign accounts on Statemint/e?

Tags: data-analytics, statemint

I would like to run analysis on activity involving Parachain sovereign account ids on Statemint.

Is there a way I can programmatically retrieve a list of parachain sovereign ids on Statemint?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. There are some tools and examples already available that you can use to do this programmatically. I recommend the following post:

- [how to calculate sovereignAccount for parachain?](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/1200/how-to-calculate-sovereignaccount-for-parachain)

In your case you would want `b"sibl"` (side-to-side) and not `b"para"` (up/down).